# How to put dynamic json response in panda dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following JSON response which is dynamic, most of the fields(*bccRecipients ,replyTo, and ccRecipients*) can be empty sometimes, and sometimes it contains values

```
{
      "hasAttachments": False,
      "sender": {
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "John Henry",
          "address": "john@abc.com"
        }
      },
      "from": {
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "Mike Tyson",
          "address": "mike@xyz.com"
        }
      },
      "toRecipients": [
        {
          "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Himan",
            "address": "himan@pqrst.com"
          }
        }
      ],
      "ccRecipients": [
        
      ],
      "bccRecipients": [
        
      ],
      "replyTo": [
        
      ],
      "flag": {
        "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
      }
    }
```

Till now I have created empty dataframe with column names as follows

```
email_metadata = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Subject","SenderEmailAddress","SenderName","FromEmailAddress","FromName","ToRecipients","HasAttachments","ccRecipients","bccRecipients"])
```

Also if ccRecipients array is empty it should store Null/NaN or the values if there are multiple fields.

Example for multiple values

```
ccRecipients.emailAddress.name
1) Mike 
2) John
```

Example for empty data

```
ccRecipients.emailAddress.name
1) Null
2) Null
```

Comment: How do you want to treat multiple recipients?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

response = {...}
email_metadata = pd.json_normalize(response)
```

Updated answer after question update:

```py
import pandas as pd

def get_seperated_data(metadata, column_name):
    tmp = pd.json_normalize(metadata[column_name][0]).apply(', '.join).to_frame().T
    tmp = tmp.rename(columns={c: column_name + '.' + c for c in tmp.columns})
    return tmp

response = {...}
email_metadata = pd.json_normalize(response)

list_type_columns = ['toRecipients', 'ccRecipients', 'bccRecipients', 'replyTo']

dfs_to_join = [get_seperated_data(email_metadata, c) for c in list_type_columns]
for df in dfs_to_join:
    email_metadata = email_metadata.join(df)

email_metadata = email_metadata.drop(columns=list_type_columns)

for c in list_type_columns:
    for field in ['.emailAddress.name', '.emailAddress.address']:
        if c + field not in email_metadata.columns:
            email_metadata[c + field] = None
```

Comment: I am getting response of below column. how can we separate that

email_metadata["toRecipients"] 
'[{'emailAddress': {'name': 'Mike Tyson', 'address': 'mike@abc.com'}}]'

Comment: How do you want to treat multiple recipients?

Comment: It should be in the same column. like if the column name is toRecipitents.emailAddress.name

1) Mike
2) John

And if array is empty it should give NULL/NAN